# GITLAB CE avatar don't display

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

My Gitlab CE private server has a problem with avatar, they are not showing up. I try with and without gravatar, and it is the same problem.

When i try to add or update my account avatar, i can upload it and save it without any problem.

Just after profile validation, avatar show up in the interface, but if i refresh browser, avatar disappear.

I use `gitlab-ctl tail` to log the update and there is no errors:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
Started PUT "/-/profile" for xx.yy.zz.ttt at 2022-04-21 11:28:50 +0200
Processing by ProfilesController#update as JS
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"status"=>{"emoji"=>"blush", "message"=>"", "availability"=>"not_set"}, "timezone"=>"Paris", "name"=>"xx yy", "id"=>"3", "pronouns"=>"", "pronunciation"=>"", "email"=>"xxx@yyy.fr", "validation_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "public_email"=>"", "commit_email"=>"xxx@yyy.fr", "skype"=>"xxx.yyy", "linkedin"=>"https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxx-yyy/", "twitter"=>"", "website_url"=>"https://www.zzzzzz.eu/", "location"=>"zzz, France", "job_title"=>"", "organization"=>"qqq", "bio"=>"", "private_profile"=>"0", "include_private_contributions"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Mettre à jour les paramètres du profil"}
Started PUT "/-/profile" for xxx.yyy.zzz.ttt at 2022-04-21 11:28:50 +0200
Processing by ProfilesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"status"=>{"emoji"=>"blush", "message"=>"", "availability"=>"not_set"}, "timezone"=>"Paris", "name"=>"xxx yyy", "id"=>"3", "pronouns"=>"", "pronunciation"=>"", "email"=>"xxx@yyy.fr", "validation_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "public_email"=>"", "commit_email"=>"xxx@yyy.fr", "skype"=>"xxx.yyy", "linkedin"=>"https://www.linkedin.com/in/xxxx-yyyy/", "twitter"=>"", "website_url"=>"https://www.zzzz.eu/", "location"=>"zzz, France", "job_title"=>"", "organization"=>"zzz", "bio"=>"", "private_profile"=>"0", "include_private_contributions"=>"0", "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f3f88e0c490 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:>, @original_filename="avatar.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"avatar.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">}}
Redirected to https://qqq.zzz.eu/-/profile
Completed 302 Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 4.6ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 8779)
```

There is no error in chrome network console when reloading the profile page.

Help appeciate.

**UPDATE**

After trying many things, there is 2 differents problems.

First is with gravatar enabled. When gravatar is enable chrome block requests pointing to gravatar. Give a try with Safari and in this browser everything is ok. So for chrome i suspect that problem is chrome or extension related. Need to investigate this.

Second is with saved avatar. In this case, problem is not browser centric, but server centric because problem appear in chrome **AND**
Safari.

**UPDATE 2**

Problem is fixed for gravatar mode. Problem was with BitDefender Anti-Tracker extension which block gravatar request.

But problem presist for saved avatars.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @sytech, yes i tried, but avatar don't show up.